# (Django) One UpdateView many forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm working for my training center to develop a web application.

I have a page with a list of clients, and would like to be able to click a link to update their profile. When 'update' is clicked, I should be able to edit the username, first name, ... email, phone number, street etc, in a single page, using a single submit button. I accomplished this by using five forms, one for User, one for the extra information, one for the address, one for the zip code and one for the number of the street. The ListView, and CreateView work perfectly with these five forms, but not the UpdateView. I am not able to update the instance and it create a new instance at each submit.

The question is: what did I do wrong, please ?

Thanks.

views.py:

```
class ClientUpdate(UpdateView):
model = Client
template_name = 'garage/client_update.html'

form_class = ZipCodeForm
second_form = CityForm
third_form = AddressForm
fourth_form = DonneesPersonnellesForm
fifth_form = ClientForm
# success_url = reverse_lazy('garage/clients')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    client = self.object
    address = client.adresse
    zipCode = address.zipCode
    city = address.city
    donneesPersonnelles = client.donnees_personnelles_client
    context = super(ClientUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if 'form' not in context:
        context['form'] = self.form_class(instance=zipCode)
    if 'form2' not in context:
        context['form2'] = self.second_form(instance=city)
    if 'form3' not in context:
        context['form3'] = self.third_form(instance=address)
    if 'form4' not in context:
        context['form4'] = self.fourth_form(instance=donneesPersonnelles)
    if 'form5' not in context:
        context['form5'] = self.fifth_form(instance=client)
    return context

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    client = Client.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    address = client.adresse
    zipCode = address.zipCode
    city = address.city
    donneesPersonnelles = client.donnees_personnelles_client
    super(ClientUpdate, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
    form = self.form_class(instance=zipCode)
    form2 = self.second_form(instance=city)
    form3 = self.third_form(instance=address)
    form4 = self.fourth_form(instance=donneesPersonnelles)
    form5 = self.fifth_form(instance=client)
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(object=self.object, form=form, form2=form2, form3=form3, form4=form4, form5=form5))

def post (self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    client = Client.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    address = client.adresse
    zipCode = address.zipCode
    city = address.city
    donneesPersonnelles = client.donnees_personnelles_client

    self.object = self.get_object()
    form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=zipCode)
    form2 = self.second_form(request.POST, instance=city)
    form3 = self.third_form(request.POST, instance=address)
    form4 = self.fourth_form(request.POST, instance=donneesPersonnelles)
    form5 = self.fifth_form(request.POST, instance=client)

    if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid() and form3.is_valid() and form4.is_valid() and form5.is_valid(): 
        zipCodeData = form.save(commit=False) 
        cityData = form2.save(commit=False)
        addressData = form3.save(commit=False)
        donneesPersosData = form4.save(commit=False)
        clientdata = form5.save(commit=False)

        zipCodeData.save()
        cityData.save()
        addressData.save()
        donneesPersosData.save()
        clientdata.save()
        messages.success(self.request, 'données sauvegardées avec succes')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
    else:
        return self.render_to_response(
          self.get_context_data(form=form, form2=form2, form3=form3, form4=form4, form5=form5))

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('garage/clients')
```

solution found :

```
    class ClientUpdate(UpdateView):
        template_name = 'garage/client_update.html'
        success_message = "Données mises à jour avec succès"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        client = Client.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        address = client.adresse
        zipCode = address.zipCode
        city = address.city
        donneesPersonnelles = client.donnees_personnelles_client
        form = ZipCodeForm(instance=zipCode)
        form2 = CityForm(instance=city)
        form3 = AddressForm(instance=address)
        form4 = DonneesPersonnellesForm(instance=donneesPersonnelles)
        form5 = ClientForm(instance=client)

        context = {'form': form, 'form2': form2, 'form3': form3, 'form4': form4, 'form5': form5, }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post (self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        client = Client.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        address = client.adresse
        zipCode = address.zipCode
        city = address.city
        donneesPersonnelles = client.donnees_personnelles_client

        form = ZipCodeForm(request.POST, instance=zipCode)
        form2 = CityForm(request.POST, instance=city)
        form3 = AddressForm(request.POST, instance=address)
        form4 = DonneesPersonnellesForm(request.POST, instance=donneesPersonnelles)
        form5 = ClientForm(request.POST, instance=client)

        if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid() and form3.is_valid() and form4.is_valid() and form5.is_valid(): 
            zipCodeData = form.save(commit=False) 
            cityData = form2.save(commit=False)
            addressData = form3.save(commit=False)
            donneesPersosData = form4.save(commit=False)
            clientData = form5.save(commit=False)

            cityData.save()
            addressData.city = cityData


            zipCodeData.save()
            addressData.zipCode = zipCodeData


            addressData.save()
            clientData.adresse = addressData

            donneesPersosData.save()
            clientData.donnees_personnelles_client = donneesPersosData

            clientData.save()
            return redirect('garage:clients')
        context = {'form': form, 'form2': form2, 'form3': form3, 'form4': form4, 'form5': form5, }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        client = Client.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        address = client.adresse
        zipCode = address.zipCode
        city = address.city
        donneesPersonnelles = client.donnees_personnelles_client
        context = super(ClientUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if 'form' not in context:
            context['form'] = self.form_class(instance=zipCode)
        if 'form2' not in context:
            context['form2'] = self.second_form(instance=city)
        if 'form3' not in context:
            context['form3'] = self.third_form(instance=address)
        if 'form4' not in context:
            context['form4'] = self.fourth_form(instance=donneesPersonnelles)
        if 'form5' not in context:
            context['form5'] = self.fifth_form(instance=client)
return context
```

Comment: When you say you the code does not update the instance, are you referring to the Client model instance? And is there a reason why you are using 5 forms?

Comment: I also think you may be misunderstanding how to use the `UpdateView`. Have a read in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview) and this useful [page](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested and Segmented Crispy Layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48363231/nested-and-segmented-crispy-layouts)

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48363231/nested-and-segmented-crispy-layouts

Comment: I have to separate sensitive data because of an european law.

I need to update all models, but it's ok. I found how I can do.
I post my solution ;)